# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>) javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having a bit different issue regarding javascript on my aspx page. I am not using any Masterpage at the moment well the said configuration is working fine in another project but i m banging my head and googled the solution but still searching...

MY ASPX CODE

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="comp1.aspx.cs"      Inherits="StudentManagement.comp1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
    <title>
        Submit / Update Complains
    </title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/structure.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/form.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Submitbtn.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/MenuMaster.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Logout.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Logoutbtn.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/impromptu.css"/>

     <!-- JavaScript -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">     </script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/wufoo.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-impromptu.2.6.min.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript">

        function confirmSubmit() {
        $.prompt('Are you sure you want to submit?'
            , {
                buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }
                , callback: confirmSubmitResult
            }
        );
        return false;
    }

    function confirmSubmitResult(v, m, f) {
        if (v) //post back if the user clicked OK
            $('#<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
    }
    </script>


</head>
```

Little help will be highly obliged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Response.Write block within a runat="server" tag. Have a look at [this post](http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/) for the reasons behind this and a fix:

**Javascript:**

```
 function confirmSubmitResult(v, m, f) {
        if (v) //post back if the user clicked OK
            $('#<%# btnSubmit.ClientID %>').click();
    }
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Page.Header.DataBind();    
   }
```

Comment: That's really a separate issue. Start by checking the ClientID being outputted is correct, then check that confirmSubmit is really called.

Comment: I followed your guidleine however the error dissapeared but my code is not running  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string prompt = "<script>$(document).ready(function(){{$.prompt('{0}!');}});</script>";
            string message = string.Format(prompt, "This message is coming after postback");
            
            
            if (TextBox2.Text.Length == 0 || TextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "message", message);
           

            }

Comment: Mike, my answer was for your issue regarding the error in the question title. This comment really deserves another question on it's own.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. I appreciate your help...can you guide me for code behind ?